# Angular 2 token and auth

Tags: angular

I would create a authentification in angular 2. I create a post service:

```
constructor(http: Http) {
    this.http = http;
    let currentUser: IUserTokenType = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("currentUser"));
    this.token = currentUser && currentUser.token;
}
public loginC (username: string, password: string): Observable<boolean> {
     return this.http.post( authURL + loginURL,
                             JSON.stringify({  password, username }))
     .map((response: Response) => { 
         let token: string = response.json() && response.json().token;
         if (token) {
             this.token = token;
             localStorage.setItem("currentUser", JSON.stringify({ token, username}));
             return true;
         } else {
             return false;
         }
     });
 }
```

And a `login()` function:

```
private router: Router;
private authenticationService: ServerDataComponent;
constructor (router: Router, authenticationService: ServerDataComponent) {
    this.router = router;
    this.authenticationService = authenticationService;
}
public login(): void {
    this.loading = true;
    this.authenticationService.loginC(this.model.username, this.model.password)
        .subscribe((result: boolean) => {
            if (result === true) {
                this.router.navigate(["table_per"]);
            } else {
                this.error = "Введен неверный логин и/или пароль";
                this.loading = false;
            }
        });
}
```

And this is my template:

```
<form name="form" class="form col-md-12 center-block">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" [(ngModel)]="model.username" placeholder="Логин" name="username">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="password" class="form-control input-lg" [(ngModel)]="model.password" placeholder="Пароль" name="password">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <button (click)="login()" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" type="submit">Войти</button>
      </div>
      <div *ngIf="error" class="alert alert-danger">
        {{error}}
      </div>
    </form>
```

And when i click on button login i have this error: `Unexpected of json input`. Maybe angular doesnt read token?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to declare names for your JSON-properties.

There are two faulty JSON-objects!

```js
JSON.stringify({ 'password': password, 'username': username })
JSON.stringify({ 'token': token, 'username': username})
```

```js
public loginC (username: string, password: string): Observable<boolean> {
   return this.http.post( authURL + loginURL, JSON.stringify({
         'password': password,
         'username': username
      }))
     .map((response: Response) => { 
         let token: string = response.json() && response.json().token;
         if (token) {
             this.token = token;
             localStorage.setItem("currentUser", JSON.stringify({ 'token': token, 'username': username}));
             return true;
         } else {
             return false;
         }
     });
 }
```

Comment: i declare, but nothiong happens

Comment: look, i enter in login form login and password, then i post in server login and password, and then server send me session and redirect to another page. But redirect doesnt complete, and i get error of unxpected json

Comment: See my updated answer, there was another `stringify` I didn't saw before..

Comment: This works without "username" and "password". But redirect doesnt works